# Why is there a hash in my URL path and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my Angular app, using `ui-router`, when I go to any of my states in my app, the URL that appears in the browser is something like

```
http://localhost/budgeteering/v4/src/app/#/user/joe
```

It's the hash in there that is confusing me.

Why is it there and how do I get rid of it? It's causing some problems with `<a href="#">` tags and is otherwise annoying.

Here's what my states look like:

```
          .state('user', {
                abstract: true,
                url: '/user/:username',
                resolve:{
                    username: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
                        return $stateParams.username;
                    }]
                },
                controller: 'userCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'user/userhome.html'
            })
```

Comment: Have you solved this issue yet by chance?

Comment: @salniro still no, I plan to work more on it in two days. If you come up with something let me know

Comment: well I provided an answer that will solve your issue. Have you tried it yet?

Answer (score 0):

Angular 1.3 requires a notion of a `<base href="">` see **[docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase)**. Asuming you'll change the following code if you need one, enter the configuration to leverage html5 routing (and removing the hash)

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });

    //[.. state stuff ..]
}]);
```

Before Angular 1.3 this was just `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`